# Export table to excel in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, excel

I have a table with many pages of results (14 columns) that would like to export to Excel, what's the easiest to achieve that on AngularJS i.e. to export all results not one page only?
Thank you for help and answers :)

Comment: If you are fine with the csv export, then there is a quickest way to do that, I can help you out with that/

Comment: @undefined yes please can you share a solution

Answer (score 0):

```
var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
    });
    saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
};
```

you can try like this

check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/XNVj3/1/

Comment: and what if I don't want to exclude any external js for performance issue?

Comment: @Vinoth i got to work :)  but now only export the visible page, i.e. I have 10 pages of results how can I show all of them not only the first page?

Answer (score 0):

I found the follow code with the export of excel using Angular

Basically it generates a xls base on this :

```
    $scope.jsonToExport = [
{
    "col1data": "1",
  "col2data": "Fight Club",
  "col3data": "Brad Pitt"
},
{
    "col1data": "2",
  "col2data": "Matrix (Series)",
  "col3data": "Keanu Reeves"
},
{
    "col1data": "3",
  "col2data": "V for Vendetta",
  "col3data": "Hugo Weaving"
}  ];
```

check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/kursadgulseven/cd0fmg0r/